# Sending data from servlet to jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a form in a jsp from which i am retrieving data to servlet via doPost method, suppose username and password now there is an empty textarea field inside the same  form  where i want to send the username from servlet,how do i do it?

Comment: are you trying to create a login ?

Comment: Please post your code , so that it will help others to find solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your case. But there're 2 common ways to send data from servlet to JSP:

**Request attributes**: you can use this if data is transferred along a same request.

```
request.setAttribute("username",obj);
request.getRequestDispatcher("url").forward(request,response);
```

In JSP:

```
<div>${username}</div>
```

**Session attribute**: use this to retain data during a session

```
Session session = request.getSession(true); //true: create session if not existed
session.setAttribute("username",obj);
response.sendRedirect("url"); //or use request dispatcher to forward the request
```

In JSP:

```
<div>${username}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your Servlet class like this

```
public class ServletToJSP extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //communicating a simple String message.
        String message = "Example source code of Servlet to JSP communication.";
        request.setAttribute("message", message);

        //Servlet JSP communication
        RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("jsp url");
        reqDispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

**jsp page**

```
<%
    String message = (String) request.getAttribute("message");
    out.println("Servlet communicated message to JSP "+ message);
%>
```